# Safe way to communicate IBAN connection

Tags: email, banks

How do I securely communicate my bank connection details (IBAN + full name) to an otherwise trusted person with email being the only connection? Obviously I wouldn't use (plaintext) e-mail since any person that ever gets access to either mine or the recipient's inbox will also have access to that data.

What tricks do you use? Is there something like a trusted pastebin service with password-option and expiration date?

Comment: Yes, an encrypted pastebin service would be really useful, but I'm not sure why you need to be so secretive with an IBAN.  Can't someone only use it for deposits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something like a trusted pastebin service with password-option and expiration date?

Yes, there is.  I found it [via this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/13280/1163) and I've used it a few times now.  It is:

**https://onetimesecret.com/**

They appear to take security very seriously; but it's also open source so you could set up your own copy if you were paranoid.

I like the fact that it is guaranteed the recipient will detect if the secret has been compromised, so for something like a revocable key it's a good transport mechanism.

Comment: this seems to be the most simple and quickest solution. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is an [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) standard for encrypting and signing email so that you can provide, confidentiality, integrity and authentication towards the person who is reading your email.

Comment: I've found that OpenPGP is great for those with the know-how, but try explaining how to install OpenPGP to a non-technie for once-off usage... argh.

Comment: You can also try S/MIME which is a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a web-based encyption service like [Infoencrypt](http://www.infoencrypt.com/) or [Sendinc](https://www.sendinc.com/) for sending your emails.

They are free and they encrypt your email from end to end.

There is also an extension for google chrome, [SafeGmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/safegmail/lmjkmpdndmbieflefonjgnnfimmkbedf), although I have never used it.

Comment: An explanation on the down-vote would be highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution for secure email is exchanging public keys and using [PGP](http://www.openpgp.org/).

When you or the other party doesn't want to install PGP, a more convenient alternative is to put the data into a password-protected (encrypted) ZIP archive and tell them the password via another communication channel. However, keep in mind that some email servers might reject password-protected zip attachments because they can not scan them for malware.

Comment: Why the downvote?